# graphql + mongoose + typescript, how to reduce model definition duplicated

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I use `mongoose`, `typescript` and `graphql` to build my app.

I am a full-stack developer.

The problem is I define the fields and types of model **FIVE** times.

server side:

`models/book.ts`:

```js
// first time
interface IBook extends mongoose.Document {
  title: string;
  author: string;
} 

// second time
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String
})

const Book: mongoose.Model<IBook> = mongoose.model<IBook>('Book', bookSchema)
```

`graphql/typeDefs.ts`

```js
const typeDefs = `
  // third time
  type Book {
    title: String!
    author: String!
  }

  // fourth time
  input BookInput {
    title: String!
    author: String!
  }
`
```

client side:

`interfaces/book.ts`

```js
// fifth time
interface IBook {
  title: string;
  author: string;
}
```

As you can see. the `title` and `author` fields and types are defined **FIVE** times.

There are three main disadvantages:

1. duplicated
2. lack of maintainability
3. inefficient

Is there a way to solve this? I think this is almost a **`DRY`** problem.

Here are my thinkings:

1. universal app - extract some common modules used in client and server side.
2. make a tool handle this.

   - make a project generator or command line tool like `ng-cli` for generating model and types statically which means before the run-time
   - make model definition `decorator` or `syntax sugar` generate model and types dynamically at run-time

Comment: Is there a solution yet? I like using TypeScript and Mongoose, but I am new to GraphQL and this is the very first problem that appears in my mind.

Comment: @kit Not yet. Still do not find a solution handle these "duplicated" code.

Comment: Maintain mongoose schema and graphql schema separately as they have different data types. Use Javascript object to avoid duplicate in mongoose and Types to avoid duplicate in GraphQL.

Comment: I found a module https://typegraphql.ml/,  it's useful enough for me

Comment: Thus far, this plugin is the best things I've found:
https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/ It looks like it will handle the graphql/typescript repetition. Unfortunately, there is currently no mongoose plugin, but there is a MongoDB plugin. I'm going to start looking into how to use that to make the schemas.

Answer (score 2):

We recently ran into this issue, requiring us to maintaining a duplicated Typescript interface alongside our Mongoose schemas (for us the issue was solely server-side as we are not using graphql or client-side Typescript)

We built [mongoose-tsgen](https://github.com/Bounced-Inc/mongoose-tsgen) to address this. It may not handle all cases concerned here, but could be easily bootstrapped to handle your use case.

It reads your Mongoose schemas and generates an `index.d.ts` file which includes an interface for each document and subdocument. These interfaces can be imported from the mongoose module directly like so:

```js
import { IUser } from "mongoose"

async function getUser(uid: string): IUser {
  // `user` is of type IUser
  const user = await User.findById(uid)
  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still wondering,

You can use TypeGraphQL together with Typegoose to create all the schemas within one single class with decorators like this:

```
@ObjectType()
export class Book{

@Field() @prop({ required: true })
title!: string;

@Field() @prop({ required: true })
name!: string;
}
```